# JavaScript: Trouble accessing a parent global variable from a child window

Tags: javascript

I spawn a new window thus and attach these scripts:

```
  var newwindow2=window.open('','name','height=200,width=150,menubar=yes');
  var tmp = newwindow2.document;
  tmp.write('<html><head><title></title>');
  tmp.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app-style2.css">');
  tmp.write('</head><body></body><div id="myapp"></div>');


  var headtag = tmp.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var fileref=document.createElement("script");
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("language", "JavaScript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", "js/test.js");
  headtag.appendChild(fileref);
```

In  test.js which is also attached to the opener. I have global array  of objects called contacts.   If  I add an onload function thus to see how panes is loading,  I see the array amount just fine.

```
 fileref.onload = function() {

 alert(contacts.length);
 };
```

I try to access panes and get get "null".

```
function getObj(contactID){

  for (var i=1;i<= contacts.length;i++) {
      if (contactID == contacts[i].id)
      return contacts[i];     
  }
  return null;
}
```

Any idea on where I'm going wrong?
BTW: This is demo ware and only needs to work on FF (and if possible chrome)

Comment: Where's te actual code that use `opener`?

Comment: I said the script was attached to the "opener" as well.  I am not currently using the "opener.whatever" as that did not work either. I tried contacts = opener.getContacts() in the onload script. But since it sees contacts.length is correct there. That's not the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `getObj.call(opener, TheContactID);`? If `call` is not available, try `(function(contactID){ getObj.apply(opener, arguments); })(TheContactID);`.

Comment: Bit beyond what I've done before. Does this go in the onload function?

Comment: Anywhere in the child window. As long as the `contacts` array in the parent window is already exists/filled. You'll just need to replace `TheContactID` with the contact `id` you want.

Comment: The second method which uses `apply`, has error. It's missing a `return` statement. Please use this instead: `(function(contactID){ return getObj.apply(opener, arguments); })(TheContactID);`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks Jay... Got it to work with a global contacts in the child  header like this <script>var contacts = window.opener.getcontacts(); </script>